# WAMPSERVER localhost leads me to IIS

Tags: wampserver

I have installed wampserver and when I click on localhost it show me IIS, even I disabled IIS in Control Panel, and when I test 80 port it gives me nothing, just the Apache and PHP of wampserver, please help me what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When IIS is installed it also normally comes with some other features that use port 80.

Check for these as well

```
Web Deploy 2.0 (Web Deployment Agent Service)
MS Sql Server Reporting service.
BranchCache ( Windows 8.1 )
SQL Server VSS Writer
```

Comment: From where I can check all these?

Comment: In Programs and Features, Turn Windows Features On and Off

Comment: @RiggsFolly will you please tell me under which section I have to do change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823365/mysql-wamp-server-is-not-working-after-win10-upgrade/31828109#31828109