# MySQL- Wamp server is not working after win10 upgrade

Tags: mysql, wamp, windows-10

I just upgrade to windows 10. after upgrade my MySQl is not starting, wamp server icon orange , I can see Apache server is running but MySQL is not running.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Note to self: Don't upgrade

Comment: please check mysql logs and share....

Answer (score 3):

------- SOLVED ---------

This is what worked for me

I went to /wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data

And deleted following

auto.cnf , xxxxxxxx.err,  xxxxxxxx.pid , xx_logfile0 , xx_logfile1

And restarted , It worked !!

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

W10 seems to install IIS by default, and as that is a web server too and started automatically at boot, it grabs port 80 before you can start WAMPServer(Apache). 
So if you dont want IIS then uninstall it and you will get access to port 80 again.

To test this is the problem before uninstalling you can stop IIS from the command line, so Start a command window, you probably need to start it using the "Run as Administrator" option, then run

```
 iisreset /stop
```

Then start WAMPServer, or restart Apache from the wampmanager menus and see if it comes up and goes green.

There are a few other things that used to come with IIS that also shared port 80 (ms seem to have something that allows their code to share port 80) so it may be a good idea to look for these things as well.

- Web Deploy 2.0 (Web Deployment Agent Service)
- MS Sql Server Reporting service.
- BranchCache
- SQL Server VSS Writer

If you dont uninstall IIS, and the other things, you will have to stop it every time you want to run WAMPServer as it will probably start itself again at the next reboot.

***Additional Info on finding what is using port 80***

This is one way to ask the system what is using port 80. Open a command window and run -

```
netstat -anop TCP | find ":80"
```

You will get a result something like this

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3660
  TCP    192.168.2.11:49758     216.58.208.42:80       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.2.11:49772     216.58.209.238:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.2.11:49775     62.24.201.41:80        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.2.11:49777     62.24.201.194:80       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.2.11:49805     204.193.144.41:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.2.11:49810     198.252.206.17:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.2.11:49811     198.252.206.17:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.2.11:49812     198.252.206.17:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.2.11:49813     104.16.106.85:80       ESTABLISHED     7904
```

In column 2 look for :80 then put the number from the last column (the pid) into this command

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq 3306" /FO TABLE /NH
```

and you should get something like

httpd.exe                     3660 Services                   0     20,224 K

In my case its httpd.exe which is Apache but in yours it should identify any other process that is using port 80. Those programs need to be either reconfigured not to use port 80 or stopped or uninstalled.

Comment: I used that, and it did stop internet service successfully and I restarted wamp but it is still not working...

Comment: What about the other 4 things I mentioned?

Comment: I did check those in "Turn  Windows feature on or off" but i didn't find those there, do I need to look for those at some other place? I did reinstall wamp, after reinstall it worked but after I restarted the computer it goes back to same issue, Apache server is running by MySql is not ....

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the 2 services are still installed. They weren't for me. To reinstall them use (from WAMP's icon tray menu):

   Apache > Service > Install Service
   MySQL > Service > Install Service
2. Make sure no other app uses port 80 which is the default for Apache (unless you have changed it). Some apps that use it are Skype (just close it) and IIS (which is another web-server built by MS - just stop the `default web site` which uses port 80 by default from IIS Manager). This maybe of help identifying the process if you run into problems: [Upgraded to Windows 10 and now WAMP won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713586/upgraded-to-windows-10-and-now-wamp-wont-work/33198518#33198518).
3. Restart all services from the menu.

That should do it.
It certainly did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing/re-installing MSVC2012 VC11 C/C++ runtime library and restart wamp

Comment: Thanks for the respond, I did install that, I also went to MySQL>Service>Install Service  but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Which version of WAMP You are Using. I have same problem under WAMP server 2.2 I have fixed the issue by installing Microsoft Visual C++ Library 2012 & 2013.

What i have done extra is clear Environment variable for WAMP PHP; which is sets for my composer; and again Reinstall WAMP to get rid from it.

Comment: I have version 2.5 which version of Microsoft Visual C++ Library should I reinstall ?  thanks

Comment: Apache server is running, MySQL is not