# Wamp server not starting in windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I have just installed a wamp server after my windows 10 upgrade. And the issue I am facing is not being diagnosed. When I "start the services", the Wamp icon becomes orange and it says 1 of 2 services running. I have changed the port to 8080, I even changed the port of MySQL to 3307. The apache error and access logs, and PHP error log are totally blank. MySQL log is:

```
2016-04-28T07:54:26.164625Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*3072 to 2*320 pages, LSN=2471251
2016-04-28T07:54:26.275792Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2016-04-28T07:54:26.355323Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=2471251
```

Comment: if skype is running, quit it and restart wamp

Comment: Skype can't create the issue because I changed the port already.

Comment: Windows 10 installs IIS by default. If you are not going to use it, I suggest you uninstall it. That will be using port 80 and so possibly will other stuff also installed at the same time [See this post for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823365/mysql-wamp-server-is-not-working-after-win10-upgrade/31828109#31828109)

Comment: Also [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598500/wamp-server-doesnt-work-properly-on-windows-10/36598628#36598628) You will need to install the MSVC runtimes again and probably re-install the Apache and MySQL services

Comment: Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 was missing. I installed it and now everything is working totally fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you please install recommended .netframeworks for Microsoft after complete installation restart your system and it will work i am sharing the link for Network Frameworks. Please visit: https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=49982